# Refresh listview after renaming a file using base adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am getting my folder files in listview through arraylist . @ on click on something I rename a file but my listview is not refresh by using adapter.datasetnotifychanged. I am using custom base adapter. can any tell me how I automatically refresh list after "rename from" to "rename to" file.

Adapter.class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> countryList;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<String> countryList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.countryList = countryList;

    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return countryList.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
    String hello = countryList.get(position);
    Log.d("Hello",hello);

    TextView country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    country.setText(hello.substring(0, hello.lastIndexOf(")")+1));

    return view;
}
```

Rename.class

```
 File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/MoreData/closed");
   FilesInFolder = GetFiles(yourDir);
   if(FilesInFolder!=null) {
   customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), FilesInFolder);
   lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final File file = new File(path.get(position));
            value_new = FilesInFolder.get(position).toString();
            File from = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()));
            File to = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()).substring(0,file.getName().lastIndexOf(")")+1)+newencrypt);
        from.renameTo(to);}


public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(File DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(String.valueOf(DirectoryPath));
    f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
    }  
    return MyFiles;
}
 private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if(!dirPath.equals(root))
    {
        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);
        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());
    }

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];

        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            }else{
                item.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() method after renaming a file.

Comment: tried!!! but no luck :(

Comment: Please check the return value of renameTo() function. If it is true, then only the rename was successful.

Comment: itz successfull !!! i checked on file manager

Comment: itz done by putting notifyDataSetChanged() + update data by @Gordak !! but not refresh the fragment!! i put a list into fragment!!!!

Answer (score 1):

call notifyDataSetChanged() inside of onclick

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final File file = new File(path.get(position));
        value_new = FilesInFolder.get(position).toString();
        File from = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()));
        File to = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()).substring(0,file.getName().lastIndexOf(")")+1)+newencrypt);
    from.renameTo(to);
  //after renaming it will refresh listview
  customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` should be also called in your onItemClick() in the end

Answer (score 0):

[notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) will only redraw the listview, which uses the adapter to know what to draw. Your adapter uses an ArrayList as data input. If this object is not changed before notifyDataSetChanged is called, the ListView will remain exactly the same.

To reflect the changes in your list, you must change the data attached to your adapter. So you should provide a method to allow to modify your adapter data.

For example, add this method to your CustomAdapter:

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<String> countryList) {
    this.countryList = countryList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then when an item is clicked, adapt the list of files accordingly and update your adapter.

**UPDATE:**

```
   File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/MoreData/closed");
   FilesInFolder = GetFiles(yourDir);
   if(FilesInFolder!=null) {
   customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), FilesInFolder);
   lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final File file = new File(path.get(position));
            value_new = FilesInFolder.get(position).toString();
            File from = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()));
            File to = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()).substring(0,file.getName().lastIndexOf(")")+1)+newencrypt);
            from.renameTo(to);


           File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/MoreData/closed");
           FilesInFolder = GetFiles(yourDir);
           if(FilesInFolder!=null) {
               customAdapter.updateData(FilesInFolder);
           }

      }
```

Comment: Whenever you want to refresh your listview. Once a file is renamed for example. Just call customAdapter.updateData(updatedList).

Comment: i uses this == File from = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()));
            File to = new File(root,String.valueOf(file.getName()).substring(0,file.getName().lastIndexOf(")")+1)+newencrypt);
            from.renameTo(to);
            customAdapter.updateData(FilesInFolder); but not refreshing the list

Comment: Well... How do you build your adapter in the first place ? Look at what you wrote before the method on click.  In the onClick method, after you renamed the file (or whatever you do), just do exactly the same as what you did to initialize your adapter.

Comment: i think the problem is i inflate my files to list view by this method (GetFiles) and renaming file by using this method (getDir).. i update my code!!

Comment: if(FilesInFolder!=null) {
            customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), FilesInFolder);
            lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);      
            customAdapter.updateData(FilesInFolder);
        }        this is my code after update but no luck :|